# Codeigniter Tank Auth - removing 'index.php' from config leads to endless loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

I've installed a base install of the **Tank Auth** authentication library for Codeigniter from here: https://github.com/ericbae/XTA2/

Everything works well, until I remove 'index.php' from my config.php file:

`$config['index_page'] = '';`
`$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;`

Now my browser goes into an endless redirect loop, and tells me:

> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete.

Firebug looks like this:

[image]

and my htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks All -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /path/to/my/site/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

This is the normal htaccess file which I use with many other codeigniter projects and it seems to work well with those.

**What on earth could be causing this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing

`$config['uri_protocol']` did the trick for me

from:

> $config['uri_protocol']   = 'PATH_INFO';

to

> $config['uri_protocol']   = 'REQUEST_URI';

fixed this for me.